# Regex two string variables

Tags: javascript, regex

Say I have two string variables:

```
a = 'LOVE';
b = '....';
```

How do I use regex (or whatever else is fastest) to combine a + b to make:

```
c = 'L.O.V.E.';
```

In my case, both strings are 4 characters long, always, and the second string is not a fixed character, I just made it a dot to make it look clearer on screen.

Comment: The strings should match in length? Another question: the other string is usually a fixed character like "." or something similar?

Comment: in my case, both strings are 4 characters long, always. and the second string is not a fixed character, I just made it a dot to make it look clearer on screen.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can simply loop through the longer string and in each iteration append one character from both strings to your resulting string. I don't think you need any regular expression there:

```
a = 'LOVE';
b = '....';

var combinedString = ''; 
var largerLength = Math.max( a.length, b.length );

for( var i = 0; i < largerLength; i++ )
{
  combinedString += a.charAt(i) + b.charAt(i);
}//for()

console.log( combinedString );
```

The above code will work for strings of any length. In case, you know beforehand that both strings are exactly 4 characters long, I think the fastest and most efficient way would be:

```
a = 'LOVE';
b = '....';
var combinedString = a.charAt[0] + b.charAt[0] + a.charAt[1] + b.charAt[1] + a.charAt[2] + b.charAt[2] + a.charAt[3] + b.charAt[3];
console.log( combinedString );
```

Comment: if they are both 4 characters long (always), can this function be simplified? Plus the reason I don't want to for loop is it takes too long, I thought with regex it will be faster.

Comment: I don't think using Regexp is faster in any way in this case. Regular expressions are also expensive and for loop is not that slow.

Comment: It would be better to catch the result of `Math.max( a.length, b.length )` before looping :)

Comment: @cocacrave, the difference would be so negligible that it won't effect anything. Moreover you do not have to worry about that because of kind of operation you are performing. It is really difficult to tell which is faster. Take a [look at here](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: @squint sorry, but I did not get how should I use it. Do you mean replacing a.charAt(i) by a.slice( i, i + 1 )? Would it not be same in that case?

Comment: shorter: `combinedString += a.charAt(i) + b.charAt(i);`

Answer (score 6):

You could use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) for it

```js
var a = 'LOVE',
    b = '....';
    c = a.split('').reduce(function (r, v, i) {
        return r + v + b[i];
    }, '');

console.log(c);
```

Comment: This works pretty good, but doesn't take care of the case when we have different string length.

Comment: try with ``a = 'AMAROK'`` and ``b = '....'`` and you'll get ``A.M.A.R.O.K.``
Which duplicate  characters that should not exist.

Comment: what happens with more dots?

Comment: You are using ``b[i] || ''``  which is **only** true if ``a.length > b.length`` what about the inverse, it is not covered here.

Comment: @hamism: There's a comment below the question stating that the strings will always have the same length. Irrespective of that, the OP hadn't given a complete set of requirements, so there would be no way to correctly answer these "what ifs".

Comment: @squint you are right sorry didn't see that comment. that information should be in the question and not in the comments in my opinion as it is an **important** detail.

Comment: @hamism: Very true. I updated the question with that info.

Answer (score 1):

How to combine `a` + `b` via **regex**:

```js
var a = "LOVE", b = "....";

var result = a.replace(/./g, (match, i) => match + b[i]);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of regex for your problem. You can simply do it with the help of for loop

```
a = 'LOVE';
b = '....';

var result = ''; 
var length = Math.max( a.length, b.length );
for( var i = 0; i <+ length-1; i++ )
{
    result = result + a.charAt(i); 
    result = result + b.charAt(i);
}

alert("Result of combined string is :"+ result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array functions on array likes (in this example strings) to iterate over it's items.

```js
var a = 'LOVE',
  b = '....',
  c = Array.prototype.map
  .call(a, (v, i) => v + b[i]).join('');

console.log(c);
```

Answer (score -2):

If your second string is always composed of `dots`, instead of repeating same characters in string, try something like this:

#### Using Delimiter

```js
var a = "LOVE";
var delimeter = ".";
var result = a.split("").join(delimeter) + delimeter;
console.log(result)
```

#### Array convert + manual concatenation

As an alternate to `string.charAt`, you can try something like this:

Note: you should do `a1[i] || ""` for cases where value can be undefined. Also you should use `.toString()` to avoid cases where both values are numeric and result will be addition instead of concatenation.

```js
var a = 'LOVE';
var b = '....';
var c = ",,,,,,,,,,,";
function mergeStr(a, b) {
  var a1 = a.split("");
  var b1 = b.split("");

  var len = Math.max(a.length, b.length)
  var r = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    r += (a1[i] || "").toString() + (b1[i] || "").toString();
  }
  
  return r;
}

console.log(mergeStr(a,b))
console.log(mergeStr(a,c))
```

Comment: PO says (in comment) the second value is not always the same.

Comment: @mortezaT There is another snippet that handles it. Delimiter case was for cases where all values were same. That was just a suggestion.

Comment: then you should change it to `a.split('').join(delimiter) + delimiter;`